# How to make HTTP call over HTTPS envirnment in Chrome

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, http, https

I am trying to make a ajax call to a remotely located webservice(HTTP) using our application (HTTPS).
But I am getting following error.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://test.tes.com/url' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://129.211.25.5:8063/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS
```

I am using chrome browser.

I tried to search for the solution but I most of place written that insecure content wont be allowed in chrome. In Internet explorer it prompt and if we allow mixed content then I am able to make call to HTTP webservice.

Also found the solution is to replace HTTP to HTTPS call. But my server is not configured to HTTPS (SSL not enabled) so I cant make that change.

My question is
Is it possible to make HTTP call from HTTP environment ?
Atlest can we bypass some HTTP calls so that above error can be avoided?(Filters or something that can help)
Or Is it compulsory to move to HTTPS environment ?

Comment: `But my server is not configured to HTTPS` - and yet **you** have code in a page that **is** configured for https ... don't you? - https is a no brainer and costs **nothing** these days https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: Actually the application from which I am calling webservice is configured on HTTPS env and the webservice located on another server which has no SSL enabled(HTTP), so its like I want   to get content from HTTP env using application's HTTPS environment

Answer (score 1):

You have two solution:

- convince the webservice to allow https (and no, an https-> redirection is not a solution)
- make the https call to your server and then configure your server to make the http request in back-end:

> user <-https-> your server <-http-> the webservice

Comment: Making webservice to allow HTTPS is one solution I got, But what if I don't have access to servers, instead I have only access to both the application.  So is there any way to allow this to happen? For example like for cross-domain calls we add filters, so can't I make such type of change at application level and allow this call to happen? I tried looking for it but didnt found anything OR its compulsory to have HTTPS..that's only solution?

Comment: From an https webpage you can't make http ajax calls.

Answer (score -3):

Here's your problem ( if you're using htaccess file):

`RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1`

You don't allow SSL requests (443 port number is used for HTTPS requests). Try removing these lines.

Alternatively,

If possible, use the `https` version of that external page/web server.

Comment: what? his server is **not configured to HTTPS** - why would he redirect (non-existent) port 443 to port 80?